# Drop down list items still clickable when the opacity is zero

Tags: jquery, html, css

The issue is that the drop-down button is still clickable when the opacity is set to zero. I am setting the opacity to zero because in need the fading effect. Is there any alternative to get an animation, as well as the content, is hidden by jquery?

You can see in the example when we hover below the button the cursor turns into a pointer and the elements are clickable.

Tried doing this but never worked

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var child = $(this).siblings();

  if (!child.hasClass("visible")) {
    child.animate({
      'opacity': 1
    }, 1000);
    child.addClass("visible");
  } else {
    child.animate({
      'opacity': 0
    }, 1000);
    child.removeClass("visible");
  }
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $(".visible").animate({
    'opacity': 0
  }, 1000);
  $(".visible").removeClass("visible");
});
```

```css
.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.btn-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: initial;
  max-height: 210px;
  overflow: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.btn-dropdown li {
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn-dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn first">Select something</button>
  <ul class="btn-dropdown">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn first">Select something</button>
  <ul class="btn-dropdown">
    <li>Black</li>
    <li>Brown</li>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try fadeIn and fadeOut instead

Comment: Methods like fadeIn & fadeOut not working with child variable IDK why? But working on the $(".visible")

Comment: dont forget to replace "opacity: 0" with "display: none" on .btn-dropdown :)

Comment: Thanks, @vnt I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because when you set `opacity` to `0`, the elements are still in the DOM, and can still be interacted with, despite the fact they cannot be seen - similar to `visibility: none`.

To fix this you should use `display: none`. You can also simplify the logic by using a combination of `fadeToggle()` and `fadeOut()`, like this:

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var $dropdown = $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(); // toggle this dropdown
  $('.dropdown .btn-dropdown').not($dropdown).fadeOut(); // hide other dropdowns
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $('.dropdown .btn-dropdown').fadeOut(); // hide all dropdowns
});
```

```css
.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.btn-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: initial;
  max-height: 210px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.btn-dropdown li {
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn-dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn first">Select something</button>
  <ul class="btn-dropdown">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn first">Select something</button>
  <ul class="btn-dropdown">
    <li>Black</li>
    <li>Brown</li>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `display: none` removes the element from DOM?

Comment: No. It just hides it in a way that it cannot be interacted with. It's the main difference between `display` and `visibility`/`opacity`

Comment: Ok thanks, @Rory McCrossan that worked and you made the code easier to understand.

Comment: Even though the issue is fixed I was curious to know why the methods like fadeIn & fadeOut did not work with child variable in my code? Can you explain me why did that happen?

Comment: It should have worked fine - it's basically what my code is doing. I can only surmise the issue was with the logic somehow.

Comment: Whoops, the mistake was that I forgot to make the `.btn-dropdown { display: none; }` instead it was `.btn-dropdown { opacity: 0; }`