# Multiple CSS/JS Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to be able to place a dropdown via CSS anywhere in my HTML prototype. This means I need to be able to place multiple dropdowns anywhere on the page.

Right now I use this to create a single dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Click here 01 </button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">link</a>
       <a href="#">link</a>
       <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

}
}

How do I create multiple dropdowns using the same Javascript?

Here is a demo that does not work: https://codepen.io/db13/pen/pLGRwr

Comment: Please save the demo and share the URL.

Comment: I just saved the codepen demo

Comment: I'm sorry, now the demo has been updated

Comment: Is that ok if you get a jQuery code??

Comment: I like how the dropdown is pure HTML/CSS/JS without JQuery, but if you have a JQuery solution lets hear it! What are you thinking?

Comment: @johnny555 gave the demo for all the 3 ways pure css approach, vanilla javascript approach and the jQuery approach.. Along with live demo hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your issue is that **ID's** should be ***unique***. Your function is calling effectively the first `#myDropdown` each time.

You can modify your function to pass `this` as a context target to it, and grab the dropdown dynamically using the class name.

Check out this example: <kbd>[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/ZxwLjo)</kbd>

Change your `onclick` to this:

```
 <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Click here 01 </button>
```

And change `myFunction` to this:

```
var myFunction = function(target) {
   target.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: This just worked for a second but then it stopped working. Can you save the codepen?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I accidentally saved over the selector when I pasted into the wrong pen. Fixed!

Comment: And also, clicking on dropdown2 doesn't close dropdown1 if it is open.

Comment: Any fix for closing open dropdowns if another dropdown is clicked?

Comment: I'm also trying to style the dropdown content position with CSS margin.

Comment: I've updated the pen to close all other open dropdowns

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by trying to style the dropdown content with margin?

Comment: can you assign a a margin (or position) to the dropdown content of only mydropdown2?

Comment: Of course, just target that with a CSS selector. `#myDropdown2 { margin-left: 100px; }` will only affect the second one, not the first (since the ID's are different.)

Comment: So close! how would you target it if it had an ID and a class?

Comment: <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="#">link</a>
           <a href="#">link</a>
           <a href="#">link</a>
        </div>

Comment: You shouldn't need to target the class since ID selectors have a specificity of **100**, and classes only have a specificity of **10**. However If you absolutely need the class for some reason, just add it to the selector. `#myDropdown2.dropdown-content { /* CSS */ }`

Comment: You may want to consider reading up on the [Specifics of CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), which will better explain it than I can in a comment thread

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help!

Comment: This thread finally got me up to '15 reputation points' so now I can "Upvote" awesome dudes like you! Thx again!

Answer (score 3):

**Pure CSS Way**

This approach is with pure CSS only

```css
#demo {
  margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#demo .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#demo .parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  color: #282D31;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius .1s linear, background .1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
  text-align: center;
}

#demo .parent:hover,
#demo .content:hover~.parent {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}

#demo .content:hover~.parent {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

#demo .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 0;
  width: 180px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

#demo .wrapper:active .content {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}

#demo .content:hover {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}

#demo .content ul {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#demo .content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#demo .content li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
}

#demo .content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#demo .content li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 1 Element 1</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 1 Parent 1 Element 1</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 1 Element 1</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 1 Element 1</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">Button 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 2 Element 1</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 2 Element 2</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 2 Element 3</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Parent 2 Element 4</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">Button 2</div>
  </div>
```

**Vanilla JavaScript**

Approach with vanilla javascript

Reference from my own GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/raajnadar/resistor-color-calculator)

```js
function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  el.style.display = "block";

  (function fade() {
    var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
    if (!((val += 0.1) >= 1.1)) {
      el.style.opacity = val;
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  }());
}

function fadeOut(el) {
  (function fade() {
    var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
    if ((val -= 0.1) == 0) {
      el.style.opacity = 0;
      el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      el.style.opacity = val;
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  }());
}

// Initialise all the required variables
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

/*
 * Button click event listeners
 * Keeps track of the button click.
 */
btn.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var sibling = btn.nextElementSibling,
      firstVisible = document.querySelector('.visible'),
      dropDown;

    /*
     * Remove the visible class if an element is already in the DOM
     */
    if (firstVisible) {
      fadeOut(firstVisible);
      firstVisible.classList.remove("visible");
    }

    if (!sibling.classList.contains("visible")) {
      fadeIn(sibling);
      sibling.classList.add("visible");
    } else {
      fadeOut(sibling);
      sibling.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var visible = document.querySelector(".visible");

  if (visible) {
    fadeOut(visible);
    visible.classList.remove("visible");
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .18);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:active {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, .4);
}

.btn-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .18);
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: initial;
  max-height: 210px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.btn-dropdown li {
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn-dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn">First Color</button>
    <ul class="btn-dropdown">
      <li>Brown</li>
      <li>Red</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
      <li>Yellow</li>
      <li>Green</li>
      <li>Blue</li>
      <li>Violet</li>
      <li>Grey</li>
      <li>White</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn">Second Color</button>
    <ul class="btn-dropdown">
      <li>Brown</li>
      <li>Red</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
      <li>Yellow</li>
      <li>Green</li>
      <li>Blue</li>
      <li>Violet</li>
      <li>Grey</li>
      <li>White</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Way**

Approach with jQuery you need an extra plugin (Sorry about that)

Reference from my own question in the past [Drop down list items still clickable when the opacity is zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46379591/5519872)

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var $dropdown = $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(); // toggle this dropdown
  $('.dropdown .btn-dropdown').not($dropdown).fadeOut(); // hide other dropdowns
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $('.dropdown .btn-dropdown').fadeOut(); // hide all dropdowns
});
```

```css
.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.btn-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: initial;
  max-height: 210px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.btn-dropdown li {
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn-dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn first">Select something</button>
  <ul class="btn-dropdown">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn first">Select something</button>
  <ul class="btn-dropdown">
    <li>Black</li>
    <li>Brown</li>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```